# Can I remove the fast scroll overlay without creating an entire custom fast scroll view?

Tags: android, android-listview, fastscroll

I have a [`StickyListHeadersListView`](http://emilsjolander.github.io/StickyListHeaders/) for which I implemented the appropriate adapter with `SectionIndexer` for fast scrolling. However the default fast scroll overlay works only with one character since the text box do not stretch with the text.

I found this [CustomFastScrollViewDemo](https://github.com/nolanlawson/CustomFastScrollViewDemo) while browsing similar questions but since I have sticky headers for my sections, I do not really need that overlay. The user knows from the header where she/he is. I would simply remove it if that was easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to implement `SectionHeader` in your adapter to enable fast scroll, you can enable fast scroll separately.

Xml:

```
<se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Code:

```
stickyListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

This applies to the standard `ListView` as well.